# Calculating interception speed

Tags: kinematics

If 2 parallel objects are traveling at 1200 m/s and 30m apart what is the minimum speed a 3rd object would have to move to intercept both objects (assuming it can only travel at 180 degrees in straight lines, horizontal to the 2 objects course). I'm not sure what to do if it is involving vectors but I managed to get this, even though its wrong... 30 x 1200= 36,000m/s

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the exact setup of this problem is but it seems like you can get the speed of the object as close to $1200 \text{ m/s}$ as you want, given enough time to intercept them.

Have the intercepting object pace the other two objects (so it's traveling alongside them).  Now add a small component of velocity toward the two objects.  The third object will cross paths with both of them eventually.

Comment: Humm imagine 2 vertical lines named A + B. A and B are traveling 1200m/s and are both 1m x 1m in size. The 3rd object is 1cm x 2cm. What is the min speed needed for that object to intercept both objects assuming it only travels in a completely horizontal lines, like a cut clean through.